# Convert a double to a String in Java and vice versa without losing accuracy

Tags: java, types

A *String* representation of a *double* is written to and read from a file by a **C#** application.

The C# application converts the double to a string using the following fragment:

```
value.ToString("R", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

The C# application converts the string to a double using the following fragment

```
double num = double.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float, (IFormatProvider) NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

If that same file were to be written to and read from by a **Java** application, how would you go about converting the types without losing data?

Comment: Note that it is not really possible to convert a double to a string without potentially losing accuracy, since some numbers (such as 0.1) cannot be represented exactly as floating-point value. This is not a problem of .NET or Java or whatever, but of the way floating point numbers work.

Comment: You can still keep the total precision double can offer you. It's just eight bytes, after all.

Comment: @Lucero Every value represented by double has a shortest decimal representation which is closer to that value than any other. This is the decimal representation used if round tripping of exact values is required. The precision lost is less than the precision represented by a double.

Comment: To add to Pete's comment - while not every decimal string is exactly representable in a double, every double *is* exactly representable as a string. While there isn't a double value of exactly 0.1, there *is* an exact string representation of the double value which is closest to 0.1.

Comment: @Lucero: a double can always be converted to a string without losing accuracy; the problem is that the double itself cannot accurately store numbers such as 0.1. This is not the problem in this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just using `Double.parseDouble()` and `Double.toString()` should work without losing data, I believe. In particular, from the docs for `Double.toString()`:

> How many digits must be printed for
>   the fractional part of m or a? There
>   must be at least one digit to
>   represent the fractional part, and
>   beyond that as many, but only as many,
>   more digits as are needed to uniquely
>   distinguish the argument value from
>   adjacent values of type double. That
>   is, suppose that x is the exact
>   mathematical value represented by the
>   decimal representation produced by
>   this method for a finite nonzero
>   argument d. Then d must be the double
>   value nearest to x; or if two double
>   values are equally close to x, then d
>   must be one of them and the least
>   significant bit of the significand of
>   d must be 0.

Another alternative, if you want to preserve the exact string representation (which isn't quite the same thing) is to use `BigDecimal` in Java.

Comment: Downvoters - please leave comments, otherwise the downvote serves little purpose.

Comment: I suspect because (like myself) they didn't fully realize the significance of your quoted text.  At face value, it seems obvious that Math.PI would be more accurate than Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(Math.PI)), but your quoted code comment seems to say that nothing is lost.  I'll give you a +1.

Comment: System.out.println(Math.PI == Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(Math.PI))); // prints "true"

Comment: I *think* I understand the answer, but it doesn't fit what I am seeing . First, the Double.toString() stop at 18 characters... which seems to be in direct contradiction with the quoted text. Second, the output for Double.toString(100d/6) and Double.toString( 0.00000000000000000000000000001d + 100d/6)) are the same...

Comment: @ADB: It sounds like you're expecting double to store more than it can - doubles don't *store* more than 15-17 significant digits; the value of 0.00000000000000000000000000001d + 100d/6 is *equal to* 100d/6, as far as double are concerned, because the more "accurate" value would require more significant digits than are available.

Answer (score 6):

Doubles have a limited precision and might not preserve the string intact. The BigDecimal class has arbitrary precission and keeps sring representation.

To convert a string into a BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("10.1234567890");
```

To Convert a BigDecimal into string:

```
System.out.println(d.toString());
```

More details here:
http://epramono.blogspot.com/2005/01/double-vs-bigdecimal.html

Comment: Bear in mind that the original value was from a C# double, which has the same range and precision.

Comment: From the question I understand that if the same operation was going to be done in Java. My point is that you need to use BigDecimal if you don't want to lose precision in operations.

Comment: I understood the question to be trying to accurately read a value which was previously a double in C#, then stored in a text file. You don't need to use BigDecimal for that.

Comment: I agree with you if that is the question interpretation

Comment: How do you interpret the question in any other way? Where is there any mention of any operation other than converting between double to string and back again?

Answer (score 6):

Do you need the string representation for any purpose, or it is merely for a textual data transport (e.g., SOAP/REST message)?

For the latter, you can convert the double value into a long using `java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double value)` and back into a double using `java.lang.Double.longBitsToDouble(long value)`. You can transport the long value as a hex-encoded string.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits(double)
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble(long)

This will preserve the exact 64-bit double value that you have, but it won't be human readable (for most! ;) ).

Comment: interesting approach, never heard that anybody used it

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to use Java Double wrapper class which is capital "D"
"Double"

int String s = Double.toString(yourDoubleVariable);

Answer (score 0):

From double to String:

```
String stringValue = Double.toString(value);
```

From String to double

```
double doubleValue = Double.valueOf(value);
```