# Do java.lang.Double.toString() and java.lang.Double.parseDouble roundtrip safely?

Tags: java, floating-point, tostring

I wasn't able to find a quick answer to this for Java from some googling, and I'm randomly curious:

For any non-`NaN` `double d`, does `Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(d)) == d`?

Comment: Just conjecture, but it sounds like it will be safe. From the description of `toString`: "There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to **uniquely distinguish** the argument value from adjacent values of type double." (emphasis mine)

Comment: I've checked the edge cases of `POSITIVE_INFINITY`, `NEGATIVE_INFINITY` and `-0.0` which the boolean expression still yields `true`. Thus I'm fairly confident that it is true for all non-`NaN`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/755467/4028085

Comment: Actually I tried `double d = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY - Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` and the boolean condition still evaluated to `true` - so it works for `NaN` as well.

Comment: @brso05 - yeah, I think you're right.  Not sure how I missed that one before posting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A (not so quick) test shows that it does:

```
@Test
public void testDouble() {
    for (double d = Double.MIN_VALUE; d<Double.MAX_VALUE; d=d+0.00001) {
        assertTrue("double does not match!", Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(d)) == d);
    }
}
```

This has been running on my machine for a while and it hasn't failed yet!

Comment: I don't think that will ever complete. Eventually the value of `d+0.00001` will underflow.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running something similar (only using Double.longBitsToDouble to generate my doubles) right now - but it looks like that could literally take days :p

Comment: Could use `Math.nextUp` instead.

Comment: I don't think it will underflow as the double is being incremented not decremented? I'll leave it running over the weekend :)

Comment: It will underflow as soon as `d` becomes large enough for its ULP greater than your step size. At that point you have an infinite loop.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't quite understand this problem, could you explain a little further? what do you mean by step size in this context?

Comment: @Kieran The precision of doubles varies depending on how large they are. A value close to zero will be able to represent many different values in the range `[d, d+0.00001]`. But for a large value, the next largest representable number could be more than `d+0.00001`. So you'll find a situation where `d == d+0.00001` will return true, due to the loss of precision.

Comment: As a familiar example, above 2^56 ULP becomes larger than 1 so even d+1 will equal d.

Comment: @resueman / Marko, Understood. Thanks for the explanations